# Fail to set Homebrew formula editor to vim in fish shell

Tags: vim, editor, homebrew, fish

I have a problem with *Homebrew* editor: *Atom* is used instead of *Vim*

```
$ brew edit a_brew_formula
Editing /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/a_brew_formula.rb
Warning: Using atom because no editor was set in the environment.
This may change in the future, so we recommend setting EDITOR,
or HOMEBREW_EDITOR to your preferred text editor.
```

`EDITOR` and `HOMEBREW_EDITOR` are well set in `config.fish`:

```
set EDITOR vim
set HOMEBREW_EDITOR vim
```

I checked in the shell:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
vim
```

Why my editor choice is not taken into account?

Comment: You might also want to set `VISUAL` variable to vim

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/4667

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't exported the variable, so external processes (like homebrew) don't see it.

Use `set -x`, but preferably `set -gx` to also define global scope on the variable.

E.g.

```
set -gx EDITOR vim
```

---

To see what an external process sees, you can use `env`. If called without arguments, it will print its environment as VAR=VALUE lines.

If that doesn't show EDITOR=, you know that you've not exported your $EDITOR.

Comment: Also `set --show EDITOR`, but I don't know what version of fish introduced the `--show` option.

Comment: 2.7.0. The CHANGELOG also mentions it for 3.0.0, but that was an error.